# Using Ubuntu 16.04 on a system with 2 AMD GPUs

Tags: system-installation, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm looking to install Ubuntu 16.04 onto a new system with two GPU cards, however I can't get farther than the grub boot menu loaded onto the USB install key. Attempting to install (or try) Ubuntu results in multiple device timouts and events logged, and a hard restart required.

I believe I have ruled out hardware issues, using either card individually works fine, and I can install and use windows on the system with both cards installed just fine. If it helps the systems specs are:

AMD Rysen 5 1500X
8 Gbs RAM@ 2400 MHz
Gigabyte GA-AB350 Gaming motherboard
2x AMD R9 390

I've attempted to install both Ubuntu 17.10 and the latest version of Mint with similar errors. If there is a better flavor of Linux for dual GPU system compatibility.

I'm not sure what else to try, and I don't have a ton of experience with Linux or Ubuntu (always looking for more), any suggestions are welcome. Also if this is a duplicate issue I apologize, please point me to the correct thread.

Comment: You already tried *all* the boot codes (like `nomodeset`) and nothing lets it boot? Does any linux boot with just one video card installed?

Comment: With one card (either one, both are verified working), the system works as expected and the install goes smoothly. I'm not too familiar with boot codes, ill look into code `nomodeset` and others tomorrow.

Comment: How would I add the boot codes when booting from USB? I don't have the OS installed so I'm not sure how to edit grub in livecd mode...

Comment: Please turn your last comment to a full answer and write it in the "Your Answer" window below. Then after the waiting period, you will be able to accept the answer as the correct one. Accepting your answer will help others with similar problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution (not sure if the most optimal one): adding `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt` before `quiet splash` in `grub` allows the livecd to boot and ubuntu to install. once the install was done i had to repeat the process to boot into the new os, and once more to make it permanent by editing `/etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that turning off IOMMU in the BIOS also solved this problem on that same motherboard using two RX580 cards in Ubuntu 16.04.